# Android Studio "Cannot Recover Key" while Remember passwords is ticked

Tags: android-studio, apk, jks

For some stupid reason android studio decided to start failing generating signed APK always if I dont manually enter the password each time. now it just started happening around maRCH-june this year(cant remember exactly when), until then I always just pressed next->next->finish cause i ticked the Remember passwords checkbox and everything worked great, but suddenly it started failing.

I tried generating once without checkbox and then generatin again with it
I even tried on a different computer but it still happens

If i dont enter the password manually each generation and rely on the remembered password it will always fail, even if the last generation I enetered the correct password and it generated successfuly, meanwhile entering the password each time works aslong as the password is right(like it should)

anyone knows how to fix this problem? while not stopping me from generating signed APK its annoying as hell

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by Windows 10 Controlled folder access. Try adding folder with the encryption key file to exceptions list or turn Controlled folder access entirely off.

Comment: its already off, didn't even know about this feature until now

Comment: Any other change I recall making was switching back to JRE shipped with the IDE and perhaps adding IDE related folders to exceptions of antivirus (which speeds up building and am not sure I did this after having problems with the apk key password), but not sure how any of the 2 could have had impact. Also, I am using newest stable build of IDE and Gradle, just for the record.